# IBM Worklight - encryptWebResources fails in an iOS environment

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

We need to prove a feature of Worklight about the source protection for the iOS and Android apps against repackaging. It is work on Android's app, but encountered on iOS's app and got the error message as below:

```
2013-05-16 10:55:56.296 jq[12860:3d1b] Successfully decrypted resources.zip, length:436624 Bytes
2013-05-16 10:55:56.332 jq[12860:3d1b] 54 entries in the zip file
2013-05-16 10:55:56.340 jq[12860:3d1b] Web resources integrity test is disabled.
2013-05-16 10:55:56.343 jq[12860:907] Application Error: An error occurred extracting zip file.  See earlier messages for the cause of failure.
```

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your Worklight version?

Please make sure you are using the latest available Worklight version.
Using the latest Worklight version, v6.0.0.1.20130926, I have:

1. Created a new Worklight project
2. Added the iPhone environment
3. Edited the iphone element in application-descriptor.xml with  `<encryptWebResources enabled="true"/>`
4. Built, deployed and launched in Xcode
5. Ran in the iOS Simulator

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebytB.png
[image]